# Distinct values from cell as filter - Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have country column, where multiple values can appear in a cell.

Example, for row of column "Approved By", data appears in following way (data in a cell):

[image: Column Reference Image]

Is there a way in which I can take distinct values from this column and show it as a list using slicer,
[image: Reference is the image where output needed]

in this case if I select "India" as a the value in the slicer all rows where India appears as a country should come up in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a separate table (named *Countries*) which comprises a single-column (named *Country*) of unique country names, create the following **measure**:

```
MyFilter =
VAR SelectedCountry =
    MIN( Countries[Country] )
VAR ApprovedBy =
    MIN( 'Table'[Approved By] )
RETURN
    IF( SEARCH( SelectedCountry, ApprovedBy,, 0 ), 1 )
```

You can now add *MyFilter* to the Filters Pane and set it equal to 1.